# What is the advantage of successive linearization?

Tags: control-theory, modeling

In [this link](http://au.mathworks.com/help/mpc/ug/adaptive-mpc-control-of-nonlinear-chemical-reactor-using-successive-linearization.html), two methods have been referred for linearization.

1- offline linearization

2- online linearization

However, I do not understand what is the role of "successive linearization" in the online method. What is the difference between successive and typical linearization?

Answer (score 0):

In the section "Implement Adaptive MPC Control of CSTR Plant in Simulink (R)":

> The model includes three parts:
>
> [...]
>
> 3. The "Successive Linearizer" block [...] that [...] provides the linear plant model to the "Adaptive MPC Controller" block **at each control interval**.

If you look closely, they don't make a difference between *typical* and *successive* linearization, but call *successive* linearization and *online estimation* the two typical forms of online linearization. Read the second section, "About Adaptive Model Predictive Control" again, it is actually all explained there.